# Clojure Java Interop - NoSuchMethodErrors

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have been trying some simple tests using Clojure and its Java interop capabilities, and am running into some issues. I am interfacing with the Parallel Colt Java library, trying a [LU factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) - a feature offered by Parallel Colt. I see errors of the form

"*NoSuchMethodError edu.emory.mathcs.utils.ConcurrencyUtils.getThreadsBeginN_1D*" ...

Here's some simple code I am using:

```
(ns colt-test.core
(:import [cern.colt.matrix.tdouble DoubleMatrix1D DoubleMatrix2D]
         [cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.impl DenseDoubleMatrix2D DenseDoubleMatrix1D]
         [cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.algo.decomposition DenseDoubleLUDecomposition]
         [cern.colt.list.tdouble DoubleArrayList])

;; make a 1D double array, size N of random values up to val
(defn make-1D-rand-array [N val]
  (let [v (repeatedly N #(rand val))]
    (double-array v)))

;; make a 2D double array, size NxN of random values up to val
(defn make-2D-rand-array [N val]
  (let [v (repeatedly N #(make-1D-rand-array N val))]
    (into-array v)))

;; Test LU factorization
;; matrix A size 10 x 10, random values
(def A (DenseDoubleMatrix2D. (make-2D-rand-array 5 10.0)))

;; vector b of size 10, random values
(def b (DenseDoubleMatrix1D. (make-1D-rand-array 5 10.0)))
```

I can call some functions on "b", the DenseDoubleMatrix1D, such as size(), and elements(). Also, I can call

```
set(int index, double value)
```

using the clojure interop syntax as

```
(.set b 0 10.5)
```

and it will update the first element of "b" to 10.5.

However, when I call some other methods on "b", such as

```
assign(double value)
```

as

```
(.assign b 10.0)
```

to set all the elements of b to 10.0, I get a NoSuchMethodError. Essentially, I seem to have correct calls for some interop methods, but not others, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I see the same error when I try

```
(DenseDoubleLUDecomposition. A)
```

For reference, here is the parallel colt javadoc (http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/)
Note, I am using a slightly newer version of parallel colt.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to get this to work. I was using parallel-colt 0.10.0, and when I upgraded to version 0.10.1, everything works as expected.

Hope this helps someone.